# Cannot find module 'express' while running nodemon. Throw error, app crashed

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I just created a project "project2" using "create new project : express --view=ejs project2" on a directory where I'd previously installed nodemon.

But when I typed "nodemon" on the terminal, the error says: [image]

I installed http-errors too, but the error message persists. 
What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: did you `cd project2` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. There's no change in the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I installed express inside project2 using:

```
npm install express --save
```

However, there were still more error messages such as:
"Could not find module 'cookie-parser'," which were all resolved by installing all the respective modules.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `npm install` inside the project